# Does Journey Builder use CRM Picklist label or API value in decision splits?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a Journey in MC which triggers off Salesforce Data (CRM). I have made a change to the picklist label which one of my Decision Splits use, I want to get clarification on whether decision splits use the Label or the API values to do complete comparisions?

Comment: I have this question too. I'm tearing my hair out trying to get a journey to read a value in a multi-select picklist and it is always coming back as false. Do I need to split the values out into separate fields in marketing cloud to be able to access them in a journey?

Answer (score 0):

Decision splits can be configured to use one of two types of data.

You could use journey data. This would be the data in the entry data extension.

You could also use contact data this would be the data connected to your entry data in contact builder.

If you had a synchronized data extension connected to the entry data extension in marketing cloud this would count as contact data from CRM.

Comment: While this is informational, it does not seem to answer the original question of whether label or API values are used for comparison.